# MySQL Join Users table to Groups table, find users not in any of selected groups

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

How do I write a query that takes a list of group ids (could be 1, could be 10, etc) and gets the users who are not in ANY of those groups?

We are using Doctrine, but we can't even figure out how to do it in raw SQL.

It's okay to have PHP generate part of the query if we need to do multiple joins/conditions etc based on how many ids are provided.

Comment: How should we know without the table schema?

Comment: `left join` followed by `where ... is null` is the usual pattern for that sort of filtering query.

Comment: Left join with where is null was getting us users who weren't in ALL of the groups, so if we select groups A and B, we were still getting some users who were in group A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my general assumptions about your table structure are correct, I believe something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
   FROM user_groups 
   WHERE group_id IN ([your group list])
);
```

Comment: We were trying to do it without a subselect, but this was also the only way we came up with. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jessica, it can be done without a subselect, but gets kind of odd looking:
SELECT u.user_id, ug.group_id
FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN user_groups AS ug 
   ON u.user_id = ug.user_id 
   AND ug.group_id IN ([your group list])
HAVING ug.group_id IS NULL;
(WHERE group_id might work, it has been a while since I had the need for a query like this)

Comment: Can you show me? We had several fairly smart people on it and couldn't get there ;)

Comment: @Jessica, updated it in the above comment.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that out later :) Just for fun.